# An isolation cpu cache-misses observation

Tags: cpu, cpu-cache, perf

I have an isolation cpu in cpu core 12 , and I execute the following perf command :

```
sudo perf stat -e DTLB_LOAD_MISSES.MISS_CAUSES_A_WALK,ITLB_MISSES.MISS_CAUSES_A_WALK,DTLB_STORE_MISSES.MISS_CAUSES_A_WALK,cache-references,cache-misses -C 12 sleep 10 



Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 12':

             0      DTLB_LOAD_MISSES.MISS_CAUSES_A_WALK                                   
             4      ITLB_MISSES.MISS_CAUSES_A_WALK                                   
             0      DTLB_STORE_MISSES.MISS_CAUSES_A_WALK                                   
           210      cache-references                                            
           176      cache-misses              #   83.810 % of all cache refs
```

Usually I use perf cache-misses for a process , how to interpret this : cache-misses for a cpu core ?!

Comment: Documentation for `-C` says:  *In per-thread mode, this option is ignored. The -a option is still necessary to activate system-wide monitoring.*  So you're seeing the usual not much happening in a single process that sleeps.  Note that `-C` doesn't imply pinning the process to that core, so if you *did* use `-a` then core 12 could be idle the whole 10 seconds.

Comment: @Peter , thanks , what I am curious is that core 12 has no application executed , perf -C 12 observed that 176 cache-misses , since no process executed in core 12, then how come cache-reference/cache-misses ?!

Comment: How do you conclude any of that?  It's counting stats for the `sleep` process, because you didn't specify `-a`.  Like the documentation says.  It does apparently affect the printed output, but the results make sense for `sleep` or for a core, so I'd guess the docs are correct and it's just counting stats for `sleep`.  Try it with something else that *does* use some CPU time and count some events that will have some values that aren't so close to zero.  Then try it with `-C` and with `taskset` to make that process not use core 12.

Comment: @Peter , I got your point now , thanks .